# Issue with errors about sharp when hosting next.js 14 version on vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I tried to use a library called Plaiceholder using the Next.js Server Action.
It worked fine on my Localhost environment, but after hosting I got 500 errors.

The error looks like the picture below

[image: Network error]

POST, 500 error

After that, I checked the vercel's logs and got the error that sharp could not be loaded as shown below.

```
Error: Could not load the "sharp" module using the linux-x64 runtime
```

[image: Vercel' Log]

Please let me know why this is happening.

I've tried adding and removing sharp, and lowering the version. (v 0.33.1) and re-hosted each time.

I've also tried hosting on netlify and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!

Try downgrading your SHARP version to "0.32.6"
I solved it like this.

Share the link to your issue.
https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/3870